# Android Studio: Replace main BLE data from other page

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I downloaded this sample: https://github.com/ghostyguo/BleUuidExplorer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ghostysoft/bleuuidexplorer

how it look now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIo82.jpg

the data I want as main: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBVhJ.jpg

I need the app only to advertise the HEX data from (it is not the same data). CharacteristicReadWriteActivity.java

to the main DeviceScanActivity.java
right now it show some -dBm.

all the information about the BLE device should be seen at the pictures.
it is for a school project. hope someone want to help.

Jacob

Comment: can someone plz help

Comment: can nobody help me with this ? :/